# VMs boot time is slow when Ubuntu is host

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 19.04

Currently I'm doing dual boot with Windows10/Ubuntu. The problem is that I have Oracle's VirtualBox installed on both OS, using the same virtual machine, boot time when I'm on Ubuntu is slower compared to Windows.

It doesn't matter what OS is installed on the VM, as I have had this problem with W10 and Ubuntu (yeah, the same as my real OS) as guest systems.

Is there a way to speed up VMs boot time using Ubuntu as host?